# How to place library aar's in different folders based on build variant

Tags: gradle, build, location, aar

I have a library project named 'PciLibrary' with two build types - 'debug' and 'release'. Based on the type of build, I would like the 'PciLibrary-debug' aar placed in an 'outputs\aar\debug' project folder and the 'PciLibrary-release' aar placed in an 'outputs\aar\release' project folder.

Currently, both aar outputs are being placed in a common 'outputs\aar' project folder.

My current Module build.gradle file is as follows. I suspect a simple change to the libraryVariants section will solve the problem; however, I have zero experience with Gradle. I have commented out previous attempts to solve this problem -

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    project.archivesBaseName = "PciLibrary"
}

libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        if (outputFile != null && outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
            outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}.aar"
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
```

//            useProguard false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            files('c:/Android Studio Projects/" ' +
//                    'PciLibrary/app/build/outputs/aar/debug/PciLibrary-debug.aar')
//            outputFileName("files('c:/Android Studio Projects/" +
//                    "PciLibrary/app/build/outputs/aar/debug/PciLibrary-debug.aar')")
}

```
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

//            files('c:/Android Studio Projects/" ' +
//                    'PciLibrary/app/build/outputs/aar/release/PciLibrary-release.aar')
//            outputFileName("files('c:/Android Studio Projects/" +
//                    "PciLibrary/app/build/outputs/aar/release/PciLibrary-release.aar')")
}
}

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

}